# Warning: Failed propType: (children) Dropdown - Missing a required child with bsRole: toggle

Tags: react-bootstrap

when $sugList is a empty array.

Warning: Failed propType: (children) Dropdown - Missing a required child with bsRole: toggle. Dropdown must have at least one child of each of the following bsRoles: toggle, menu Check the render method of `Uncontrolled(Dropdown)`.

`<Dropdown id={"remote-sug" + Math.random()}
                bsRole="menu"
                className="remotesug"
                onSelect={this.onSelect.bind(this)}
                open={this.state.open}
                onToggle={this.onToggle.bind(this)}>
                <input {...props}
                    className="form-control"
                    type="text"
                    style={loadingStyle}
                    onInput={$.debounce(500,me.onInput.bind(me))}
                    disabled={this.state.disabled}/>
                <Dropdown.Menu className="remotesug-list">
                    {$sugList}
                </Dropdown.Menu>
            </Dropdown>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-dropdowns-custom): "The Dropdown expects at least one component with bsRole="toggle"" That component will be used as the toggle for the dropdown, clicking it will open and close it.